# Covariance of 2 random variables

Tags: probability, covariance

Let $ X,Y $ be 2random variables.

For all $ 1\le m < k $ : $$ P\left(X=k,Y=m\right)=\frac{1}{16}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k-2}=\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k} $$
Calculate $ Cov(X,Y)$.

Using the formula $$Cov(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y] $$
I tried finding $  \mathbb{E}[XY] $ with $$ \mathbb{E}\left(XY\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\sum_{m=1}^{k}m\cdot\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\left(k^{2}+k^{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k} $$
Looking at the function$$ \frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{k}\Rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}\Rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)''=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\left(k-1\right)x^{k-2}\Rightarrow \\
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k\left(k-1\right)\left(k-2\right)x^{k-3}=\frac{1}{x^{3}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(k^{3}-3k^{2}+2k\right)x^{k}=\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)''' \\
\dfrac{x^{3}}{\left(x-1\right)^{4}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(k^{3}-3k^{2}+2k\right)x^{k}\Rightarrow\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^{3}x^{k}=\dfrac{x^{3}}{\left(x-1\right)^{4}}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-3k^{2}+2k\right)x^{k} $$
Now I can calculate $ \mathbb{E}[XY] $ ,how do I proceed from here? This seems too complicated for a seemingly elementary covariance calculation, where did I go wrong?

Comment: I would examine $E(X)E(Y)$ to see if there are some advantageous cancellations.

Comment: Has the notation been confounded? The support of $Y$ is $\{1,...,k\}$ but you also use $k$ to denote a realization of $X$

Comment: Not sure I understand what you meant by that. 
I summed $ \sum_{m=0}^{k}m=0+1+2+\dots k=\frac{k\left(k+1\right)}{2} $

Comment: I'm saying you use $k$ as both the upper bound on the support on $Y$ and as the value of $X$ correct?

Comment: Also, how is that mass function valid? How does it sum to 1?

Comment: @DannyBlozrov I think the upper bound of index $m$ is equal to $k-1$ since $m<k$ and k starts at $2$.

Comment: Please note $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k-1}{9} (\frac 34)^k = 1$

Comment: so $1 \leq m \leq k-1$ (as given $1 \leq m \lt k$)

Comment: That makes sense but I still don't think I can solve this, is the direction here really to sum 3 different series, and then doing the same with marginal mass function for $\mathbb{E}[X]$ or $\mathbb{E}[Y]$?

Comment: For $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, a shortcut would be to recognize Y|X=x ~ Uniform(1, ... x-1) and use the Tower Property.

Comment: @DannyBlozrov The first step is to edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recognize that $Y|X=k \sim \text{Uniform}\{1,\dots,k-1\}$, therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[Y\vert X] = X/2.$$

By the Tower Property,
$$\mathbb{E}[XY]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[XY\vert X]] = \mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[Y\vert X]]=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X^2],$$
and
$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y\vert X]] = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X],$$

so

$$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[YX]-\mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X]^2 = \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}(X).$$
Marginally we have
$$P(X=k) = \frac{k-1}{16}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{k-2}$$
for $k\in\{2,3,\dots\}.$

You can work out what $\text{Var}(X)$ is like you did above, or recognize $X$ as having the same distribution as a (shifted) [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) random variable, i.e. $X=X'+2$, where $X'\sim \text{NB}(r=2, p=\frac{3}{4})$. Therefore $$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}\text{Var}(X) = \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}(X') =  \frac{1}{2}\frac{2\cdot\frac{3}{4}}{\left(1-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2}=12.$$